# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name in CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I have checked all the possible things that might go wrong with my code but still it showing me this error. Please help .

```
 Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Username.(check_username)
```

And this is my code below:

```
 public function index()
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/login.php'))
        {
            /* Whoops, we don't have a page for that! */
            show_404();
        }
        $this->load->helper('security');    
        $this->load->library('form_validation'); // Including Validation Library.
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>'); // Displaying Errors in Div
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_username'); // Validation for Username Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean'); // Validation for Password field.         

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login');         
        }

        function check_username($username)
        {               
            if ($username == 'test') {                
                 $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username','already exists.');  
                 return false;
            } else {
                return TRUE;
            }               

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Have you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Do `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` in config file.

in Codeigniter-3 `xss_filtering` is not a part of form_validation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the validation language in the system folder. Check the video

```
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi71dGkn73MAhVBQI4KHeZJC2gQtwIIPTAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D56EDSocDhjk&usg=AFQjCNE_nhBpNwUOz9nkrcRYYgL50p34Kw&sig2=PSUISbtldDaWWdTyKJ6CPw&bvm=bv.121070826,d.c2E
```